# Run a process and quit without waiting for it

Tags: python, windows

In Python under Windows: I want to run some code in a separate process. And I don't want the parent waiting for it to end. Tried this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep

def count_sheeps(number):
    """Count all them sheeps."""
    for sheep in range(number):
        sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Process(target=count_sheeps, args=(5,))
    p.start()
    print("Let's just forget about it and quit here and now.")
    exit()
```

which starts the child process and continues executing. However, when the parent reaches the end, it still waits for the child to exit.

Is there a way of letting the parent quit even when the child is running? Sure, I could just run a new python interpreter using `subprocess.Popen` and feed to it the sheep-counting as a separate script.

Still, there's this whole module for playing with processes of Python code, so I'd like to take advantage of that instead of hacking on the OS. Also, it would be awesome if the same code worked everywhere where Python does, not just on Windows.

Comment: Around here I usually see the opposite problem.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `subprocess` module as other subprocess control methods (os.system, os.spawn*, os.popen*, popen2.*, commands.*) are being deprecated:

```
from subprocess import Popen
Popen( [ "foo.exe", "arg1", "arg2", "arg3" )
```

[See the Python doco](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html), especially [P_NOWAIT](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-the-os-spawn-family) example.

You will have to start a new Python interpreter in the subprocess, so "foo.exe" above will likely be "python.exe".

EDIT:

Having just reviewed the multiprocessing module documentation:

> **`join_thread()`**: Join the background
>   thread. This can only be used after
>   close() has been called. It blocks
>   until the background thread exits,
>   ensuring that all data in the buffer
>   has been flushed to the pipe.
>
> By default if a process is not the
>   creator of the queue then on exit it
>   will attempt to join the queue’s
>   background thread. The process can
>   call `cancel_join_thread()` to make
>   `join_thread()` do nothing.
>
> **`cancel_join_thread()`**: Prevent
>   `join_thread()` from blocking. In
>   particular, this prevents the
>   background thread from being joined
>   automatically when the process exits –
>   see `join_thread()`.

It looks like you should be able to call `cancel_join_thread()` to get the behaviour you desire.  I've never used this method (and was unaware of it's existence until a minute ago!), so be sure to let us know if it works for you.

Comment: cancel_join_thread() seems to be for something else: so that process may exit even when a queue it uses is not empty.

However, unless there is some queue silently created and filled in my example, I don't think this would help me here.

Comment: And thanks for the Popen examples. I already know and use the subprocess.Popen object. It's just that I hoped this could be done using the multiprocessing module instead.

Answer (score 1):

Under Linux you could `fork` but this won't work on Windows. I think the easiest way is to run a new Python process, by putting your `count_sheeps` in a seperate file and `Popen('python count_sheeps.py')`

Comment: Agreed - the only difficulty is marshalling arguments to the method.  Easy enough for count_sheeps( number ), where "number" is an integer.  For complex arguments, the multiprocessing.Process method is a clever approach!

Comment: Yeah, it's pitty fork isn't on Windows. Seems like I will have to go this route.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the process as daemon with `p.daemon = True`. As http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects says: "The significance of this flag is that the entire Python program exits when only daemon threads are left."

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep

def count_sheeps(number):
    """Count all them sheeps."""
    for sheep in range(number):
        sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Process(target=count_sheeps, args=(5,))
    p.daemon = True
    p.start()
    print("Let's just forget about it and quit here and now.")
    exit()
```

Comment: Yes but the child process will be killed when exiting. I think the OP wants it to keep going.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dirty hack if you must make it work with `Process`. Basically you just need to overwrite `join` so that when it does get called before the script exists it does nothing rather than block.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
import os


def info(title):
    print(title)
    print('module name:', __name__)
    print('parent process:', os.getppid())
    print('process id:', os.getpid())


def f(name):
    info('function f')
    time.sleep(3)
    print('hello', name)


class EverLastingProcess(Process):
    def join(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def __del__(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    info('main line')
    p = EverLastingProcess(target=f, args=('bob',), daemon=False)
    p.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to launch a pygame window from a tkinter window and close the tkinter window afterwards and found that by accident:

```
    game = Game(env)
    root.withdraw()
    game.start()
    exit()
```

Don't know if it's intended but it does what I want. (Game derives from Process.)

Answer (score -2):

You can always start a new thread, and call myNewThread.daemon(True) before invoking it's start() method.

That thread will continue to run when the main process exits.

Comment: Thanks, but not really. Daemon threads are killed when the main program  exits.

The differece from non-daemonic threads is that the program just kills them off instead of waiting for them to end on their own.

Comment: AFAICT daemon thread is exactly what the is needed in the original question. It is true though that the daemon threads are not left running, that was incorrect in this answer.